# Trying to play an MP3 through python with playsound. Not working Correctly

Tags: python

im just simply trying to play a sound with the "playsound" module but its not working, im certin i put the path in correctly. heres my code and the error.

```
from playsound import *
```

`playsound("C:\\Users\\dally\\Music\\alarm.mp3")`

error is :  Error 305 for command:
open "C:\Users\dally\Music\alarm.mp3"
Cannot specify extra characters after a string enclosed in quotation marks.

```
Error 263 for command:
    close "C:\Users\dally\Music\alarm.mp3"
The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.
```

Failed to close the file: "C:\Users\dally\Music\alarm.mp3"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\dally\Desktop\Pyhton Projects\alarmclock.py", line 4, in 
playsound("C:\Users\dally\Music\alarm.mp3")
File "C:\Users\dally\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 72, in _playsoundWin
winCommand(u'open {}'.format(sound))
File "C:\Users\dally\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 64, in winCommand
raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException:
Error 305 for command:
open "C:\Users\dally\Music\alarm.mp3"
Cannot specify extra characters after a string enclosed in quotation marks.

thank you for reading

Comment: Please edit your question to make sure that both your code and the error you get are formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

playsound version 1.3.0 has this problem , just downgrade to version 1.2.2 . it will work perfectly fine.

https://pypi.org/project/playsound/1.2.2/